# How to plot x=0 in semilogx plot?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, logarithm

I need to plot a graph using `semilogx(x,y)`. I have `x=[0 1 2 ... 10 15 20 30 50 75 100]`. The problem is that MATLAB does not plot `x=0`, which I understand because `log(0)=undef`. So is there another method in MATLAB to spread my points? Because using linear scale squeezes all first points in 1/10th of the graph's width!

Comment: Have you tried to figure out if it was possible to do it by hand and papper first? Remember log is define for all x>0 ...

Comment: Yes I know, but do you know something else to make a portion of the x-axis larger than the rest ?

Comment: If you have data at x=0 (and that data-point is important) then a log scale is likely no appropriate.  I would be nervous about using a +1 type of operation as a work-around in this situation because the result is likely a misleading plot.  Spreading out the points isn't inherently good.  You might try plotting vs x^n where n is some power instead.  There are lots of options for transforms that might improve the information you're able to convey but the important thing is to make sure that whatever transform you use is obvious.

Comment: It's important to think about what information you're trying to convey with the graph.  Applying arbitrary transforms just to spread the data out is more likely obfuscate than illuminate whatever information is important about your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually, what is done in cases like this is adding `1` to all `x`, so the first value (originally `0`) appears at the origin, and also the back-transformation is the same for all values. You can add any other small values than `1`, and get a similar result. However, you don't want to add a value that is *too* small (like `eps`) because then you get a huge distance from the next value, that will cause all other values to pack on the right side of the graph.

Let's look at an example:

```
x = [0 logspace(0,2,5)];
% x =  0    1    3.1623    10    31.623    100
y = 2.*(x+1); % add 1 to all x
semilogx(x+1,y,'o','markerfacecolor','b')
```

[image: small value]

While if you replace `0` with `eps` you get:

```
x = [0 logspace(0,2,5)];
y = 2.*(x+eps); % add a tiny value too all x
semilogx(x+eps,y,'o','markerfacecolor','b')
```

[image: eps]