# How to plot unevenly spaced data on Matlab / Origin?

Tags: matlab, plot, graph, logarithm

I want to plot my following data:

```
x-axis: [0,10,50,100,500,1000,1500]
y-axis: [75.6,78,78.2,81.8,84.7,85.2,86.3]
```

As seen above, the data on the x-axis are unevenly spaced. When I plot the above data linearly using [origin](https://www.originlab.com/), I get:
[image]

I got the similar graph on Matlab too. Notice that most of the `Amp` data lie for `x<500`. I want to plot the graph such that the whole output (y-axis) become clearly visible. For this, I tried using the **Logarithmic plot**. I changed the x-axis into logarithmic in Matlab as follows:

```
set(gca, 'XScale','log');
```

In Origin, we can use GUI to change the x-axis to logarithmic. The obtained graphs are as follows:

[image: Origin graph]

[image: Matlab plot]

The obtained graphs are still not good. Any ideas, please!

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/semilogx.html

```
x = [0,10,50,100,500,1000,1500];
y = [75.6,78,78.2,81.8,84.7,85.2,86.3];
semilogx(x,y,'.-', 'markersize', 15);
set(gca,'XTick',x);
set(gca,'XTickLabelRotation',45);
```

Comment: It helped. However, how can I plot for `x=0`? The value for `x=0` is missing in the graph. Is it due to logarithm?

Comment: [about first zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44680134/how-to-plot-x-0-in-semilogx-plot), about y2: use **hold on**

Answer (score 2):

```
x = [0,10,50,100,500,1000,1500];
y = [75.6,78,78.2,81.8,84.7,85.2,86.3];
y2 = [80,84,85,86,89,90,92];
semilogx(x+1,y,'.-', 'markersize', 15);
set(gca,'XTick',x);
set(gca,'XTickLabelRotation',45);
hold on;
semilogx(x+1,y2,'.-', 'markersize', 15);
hold off;
grid on;
legend('y1','y');
```